# jmeter and multiple http requests

Tags: http, httpwebrequest, jmeter

I need to test my web server, but I need to measure it with lot of files with different size. I got about 500-1000 that kind of files.
How to do it in jmeter?
Maybe there is an option where I can put file with my files to retrieve list?

Comment: Please elaborate.  Your question lacks detail.

Comment: Be more explicit. What do you think on file?

Answer (score 1):

Create a CSV file with the PATH for each file you need to upload.
Make ONE request that uploads a file from the csv file.
Create a FOREACH controller to make the upload request for each row in the CSV file.